# How can I practically incorporate interrupts into my embedded application?

Tags: embedded, arm, powerpc

I am working on an embedded application for an ARM platform and a PowerPC platform as well. This application is a bare-metal application so no OS whatsoever. It will perform all initialization of hardware before entering an infinite loop from where my main application logic will reside.

My main question is is there any way interrupts can be used to perform asynchronous behavior(thinking thread like functionality) to check certain characteristics of the hardware and on any hardware subsystem error, cause a reset, log the occurrence, etc. I guess I am trying to implement something like a watchdog but I want it to behave completely asynchronously and without requiring any intervention by the main application(like kicking the watchdog). Thanks!

Comment: Depends what your interrupt sources are, really. Does your platform have some sort of periodic timer?

Comment: @Notlikethat There are numerous interrupt sources, both internal and external. I would be interested to know about hypothetical uses for interrupts that are found on many different platforms. For the sake of example let's say we're using a RaspberryPi.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - hypothetically, an interrupt happens; you do stuff in response. _When_ and _why_ those interrupts happen, thus what they're useful for, depends on the actual system and its operating environment. It seems you're basically describing a lightweight RTOS; luckily those are already a thing.

Comment: It depends on how time-critical of a response is needed from an interrupt. If the action is time-critical, go ahead and handle it in the ISR. If not, better to just do the minimum to clear the HW interrupt and set a flag for the remaining processing to be done in your main loop. This prevents a long running ISR at high priority from blocking another interrupt.

Comment: In modern MCUs, which ARM and PowerPC should count among, error checking is usually done in the hardware itself. The sensible solution is to look for a MCU that has hardware support for checking these errors. Low voltage detect, clock monitoring, ECC and memory integrity etc etc.

Comment: *"a bare-metal application so no OS whatsoever"* -- Then you need to start thinking of how to abstract the code into layers, and have a micro-kernel monitoring tasks and I/O.  Do you want preemptive/competitive processing or cooperative processing (my preference)?  Whatever you do, do not misuse any ISR as a high-priority task to perform work that can/should be deferred to non-interrupt context such as a foreground task.  I've seen ISRs misused like that, and it works for the short term, but then as more work gets added, that poor design reveals itself and breaks.

Comment: You do not want to kick a watchdog in an interrupt handler. The watchdog looses its propose completely with your approach. Watchdog are meant to reset the system if the code freezes. Imagine if you have a unwanted locked loop in your main, and you keep kicking the watchdog from the interrupt? Your system is going to freeze as if there were no watchdog.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is a central loop that calls the foreground handlers.

The interrupt service routines put a value in a byte somewhere.

The foreground handlers look at that byte

The foreground and background "communicate" with that byte (or a structure of some sort)

Here's some pseudo code

```
    The_Top_Of_This_Loop:

            Call    Check_What_ISR_01_Did
            Call    Check_What_ISR_02_Did
            Call    Check_What_ISR_03_Did
            Call    Check_What_ISR_04_Did

            Call    Update_The_Rest_Of_The_System

            Jump    The_Top_Of_This_Loop
```

The foreground subroutine will do something like this (again, pseudo code, you write something real)

```
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ;                                                       ;
    ; Subroutine name: Check_What_ISR_01_Did                ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ; Looks at the indicator from the background and takes  ;
    ; the appropriate action.                               ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ; On Entry:     Nothing                                 ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ; On Exit:      Reg_00 is messed up, don't believe it   ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


    Check_What_ISR_01_Did:

            Move    Reg_00.Byte, The_ISR_01_Flag    ;The ISR Set this if he did anything
            Cmp     Reg_00.Byte, Nothing_Happened   ;Did anything happen since last time ?
            Jz      We_Are_Done                     ;No, there's nothing to do

            ;                                       ;else yes, so examine what to do
            ;                                       ;and so on
            ;                                       ; blah
            ;                                       ;  blah
            ;                                       ;   blah


    We_Are_Done:

            Return                                  ;End of foreground routine
```

The actual ISR will do something like this...

```
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ;                                                       ;
    ; Interrupt Service Routine 01                          ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ; Checks to see if a button was pushed.                 ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ; On Entry:     Nothing                                 ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ; On Exit:      The_ISR_01_Flag is updated to hold      ;
    ;               a value which the foreground will       ;
    ;               use to make a decision                  ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ;                                                       ;
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


    ISR_01:

            Push    {All The Registers And Flags}   ;This is the background; leave with no trace
            ;                                       ;Do whatever
            ;                                       ; your real
            ;                                       ;  code needs
            ;                                       ;   to do to look
            ;                                       ;    at a button 

            Move    Reg_00.Byte, Nothing_Happened   ;This is a defined constant value somewhere
            Move    The_ISR_01_Flag, Reg_00.Byte    ;The foreground routine will see this
            Jump    We_Are_Done                     ;There's nothing else to do now

    We_Are_Done:

            Pop     {All The Registers And Flags}   ;Don't forget the stack

            IntReturn                               ;End of ISR
```

Again, this is all pseudo code, use real syntax and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Round-Robin Scheduling - is what you probably need to implement or just use already existed (a number of them are open and accessible on the net).

Round-robin (RR) is one of the algorithms employed by process and network schedulers in computing. As the term is generally used, time slices are assigned to each process in equal portions and in circular order, handling all processes without priority (also known as cyclic executive). Round-robin scheduling is simple, easy to implement, and starvation-free. Round-robin scheduling can also be applied to other scheduling problems, such as data packet scheduling in computer networks. It is an Operating System concept.

In order to schedule processes fairly, a round-robin scheduler generally employs time-sharing, giving each job a time slot or quantum (its allowance of CPU time), and interrupting the job if it is not completed by then. The job is resumed next time a time slot is assigned to that process. In the absence of time-sharing, or if the quanta were large relative to the sizes of the jobs, a process that produced large jobs would be favoured over other processes.

Round Robin algorithm is a pre-emptive algorithm as the scheduler forces the process out of the CPU once the time quota expires.

For example, if the time slot is 100 milliseconds, and job1 takes a total time of 250 ms to complete, the round-robin scheduler will suspend the job after 100 ms and give other jobs their time on the CPU. Once the other jobs have had their equal share (100 ms each), job1 will get another allocation of CPU time and the cycle will repeat. This process continues until the job finishes and needs no more time on the CPU.

But before bringing RR into your application you need first to be able to enable and adjust a timer interrupt and its handler. Once you've done with processing timer IRQ you can even implement simple stuff inside it or think about RR or simple RTOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timer and routinely check on the hardware characteristics. However if the timer is regular and in sync with the clock, it is a synchronous interrupt.

Any interrupt that happens asynchronously(i.e, without being in sync with clock) can be handled by an ISR. In ARM, they refer to interrupts as exception . Based on the time required for Hardware verification, the routines to check hardware characteristics can be made in such exception handlers.

One of the main purpose of RTOS is to give time bound results and for addressing real time asynchronous events/interrupts. However, the RTOS is able to handle such multiple asynchronous tasks / interrupts due to the presence of scheduler which in turn relies on context switch. So, you may need to have a thin layer of scheduler on bare metal. The type of scheduler in term depends based on your requirement. If time is not a concern, you may just keep pushing into a queue and handle it at your own time, else you may need to have an appropriate scheduler.